# Dynamic evaluation of dependencies in a Makefile

Tags: dynamic, latex, makefile

I am writing a Makefile for a LaTex document. As part of the makefile, I only want to make a BBL file when either the corresponding BIB file changes, or (if a bibliography style is used) when the bibliographystyle.bst file changes.

In order to track file changes I am using an MD5 hash (I had problems using timestamps).

I am trying to use the following code to retrieve the required BST files from an AUX file:

```
# Get the BST dependencies from an AUX file
get-bibstyle = $(foreach bst, $(shell sed -n 's/\\bibstyle{\(.*\)}/\1/p' $1 | tr '\n' ' '), $(addsuffix .bst, $(bst)))
```

Then, I use the following code to create the BBL file:

```
# bbl: Bibtex produces .aux files from .aux files.
#      Also depends on .bst files (if they appear in the aux file).
%.bbl: $(call to-md5,%.aux) $(call to-md5, $(call get-bibstyle,$*.aux))
ifneq ($(strip $(BIB_SRC)),)
    $(IGNORE_RESULT)$(MUTE)$(VERBOSE) $(ECHO) "Building target: $@"
#   $(IGNORE_RESULT)$(MUTE)$(MOVE_TO_COL)
    $(IGNORE_RESULT)$(MUTE)$(SETCOLOUR_RED)
    $(IGNORE_RESULT)$(MUTE)$(ECHO) "===========================BIBTEX PASS================================"
    $(BIBTEX) $(*F)
    $(IGNORE_RESULT)$(MUTE)$(SETCOLOUR_LIGHTRED)
    $(IGNORE_RESULT)$(MUTE)$(ECHO) "===========================BIBTEX/LaTeX PASS================================"
    $(TEX) $(*F)
    $(IGNORE_RESULT)$(MUTE)$(RESTORE_COLOUR)
endif
```

The to-md5 function just appends .md5 to its input. `to-md5 = $(patsubst %,%.md5,$1)`

I want the dependencies for xyz.bbl to be xyz.bib and all bst files returned by running the sed expression on the xyz.aux file. I know that this has to be done with a combination of eval and call, but I haven't been able to figure it out.

At the moment, my output is as follows.

```
sed: can't read .aux: No such file or directory
make: `xyz.bbl' is up to date.
```

Comment: What where your problems when using timestamps? Is it that the timestamp updates when no content changes?

Comment: Yes that was the problem

Comment: `touch` can be used to change the timestamp of a file if there was no content change. But I wonder why a file would be rebuilt and there would be no changes in it compared to the old version...

Comment: I appreciate making these things is enjoyable, but is there any reason you couldn't just use `latexmk`, which I think does exactly what you're trying to achieve here?

Answer (score 3):

The problem with this approach

```
%.bbl: $(call to-md5,%.aux) $(call to-md5, $(call get-bibstyle,$*.aux))
```

is that Make expands the preqs before building the dependency tree (that is, without knowing what `%` is). So the first preq, `$(call to-md5,%.aux)` becomes `%.aux.md5` which will work perfectly well, but in the second preq `$(call get-bibstyle,$*.aux)` fails because `$*` evaluates to nothing and there's no such file as `.aux` to scan. (You'd have the same problem with `%`, `$$*` or whatever, the name just isn't there to extract.)

It can be done. The least Rube-Goldbergian approach I can think of is by using Make recursively:

```
-include Makefile.inc

# If there's no exact rule for this target, add it to the list, note its preqs
# and start over.
%.bbl:  
    @echo KNOWN_BBL += $@ > Makefile.inc
    @echo $@: $(call to-md5,$*.aux) $(call to-md5, $(call get-bibstyle,$*.aux)) >> Makefile.inc
    @$(MAKE) -s $@

$(KNOWN_BBL):
ifneq ($(strip $(BIB_SRC)),)
    $(IGNORE_RESULT)$(MUTE)$(VERBOSE) $(ECHO) "Building target: $@ from $^"
    ...
```

Note that this will rerun Make *for each BBL*, which may not be very efficient if you want to build a lot of them. I think there's a way to do this only once, but it'll take some more thought...